# How to build a Ruby Gem using Nix that has native extensions

Tags: ruby, nix

I'm trying to build a `bundlerEnv` for `rails`. Somehow Nix knows that `nokogiri` (a dependency of `rails`) needs `zlib`, `libxml2` and `libxslt` but compiling it fails.

```
#Gemfile
gem "rails"
```

---

```
#default.nix
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

with pkgs;

bundlerEnv {
  name = "smt";
  inherit ruby;

  gemfile  = ./Gemfile;
  lockfile = ./Gemfile.lock;
  gemset   = ./gemset.nix;
}
```

---

[full output](https://gist.github.com/pekhee/e64c77a52fd19b7a682efb3f313c1688)

```
$ nix-build
...
buildFlags: --use-system-libraries --with-zlib-dir=/nix/store/dn9l2kd6ai731k34pzlzr5dz3in0rn31-zlib-1.2.8-dev --with-xml2-lib=/nix/store/9w15hz68wz5qnihfhsbr281d0sfs20a8-libxml2-2.9.3/lib --with-xml2-include=/nix/store/rq94vzxa92p30prfgv9jz83xiy8hkn2k-libxml2-2.9.3-dev/include/libxml2 --with-xslt-lib=/nix/store/fv137j5wxp4dg1wjqdbk8i2l087163b7-libxslt-1.1.28/lib --with-xslt-include=/nix/store/j7y29aggnzmlgh5bccp9f7vmiknh16fm-libxslt-1.1.28-dev/include --with-exslt-lib=/nix/store/fv137j5wxp4dg1wjqdbk8i2l087163b7-libxslt-1.1.28/lib --with-exslt-include=/nix/store/j7y29aggnzmlgh5bccp9f7vmiknh16fm-libxslt-1.1.28-dev/include
WARNING:  You build with buildroot.
  Build root: /
  Bin dir: /nix/store/z26mymfryhqqh7y8w94qr0xc88q46dvr-ruby2.3.1-p0-nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.1/bin
  Gem home: /nix/store/z26mymfryhqqh7y8w94qr0xc88q46dvr-ruby2.3.1-p0-nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.1

...
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Unfortunately running `find /nix -name mkmf.log` fails. But manually configuring `nokogiri` using Nix environment succeeds ([detais](https://gist.github.com/pekhee/e64c77a52fd19b7a682efb3f313c1688))

Comment: [bundlerEnv's source](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/b0f8416c5c0e5345897832ae0cce139ed85c7fdb/pkgs/development/ruby-modules/bundler-env/default.nix) - [gitlab's package that basically does this](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/2acea211558fa2d462a9427b24ea15ecedb418c2/pkgs/applications/version-management/gitlab/default.nix)

Comment: [sample rails conf](http://lists.science.uu.nl/pipermail/nix-dev/2015-April/016745.html) and [an issue with gitlab](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/14478) are basically doing same thing but apparently without this problem.

Comment: downgrading `nokogiri` from 1.6.8 to 1.6.7 solves the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I've had some luck with a config like this:

```
with import <nixpkgs>{};

let
  bundler_ = bundler.override {
    ruby = ruby_2_3;
  };
  bundix_ = bundix.override {
    bundler = bundler_;
};

  gems = bundlerEnv {
    name = "company-bundler";
    inherit ruby_2_3;
    gemfile = ./Gemfile;
    lockfile = ./Gemfile.lock;
    gemset = ./gemset.nix;
  };

in

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "company-tools";
  version = "0.1.0";
  buildInputs = [
    # Ruby
    ruby_2_3
    bundler_
    bundix_
    rake
    gems

    # Nokogiri
    libiconv
    libxml2
    libxslt
    zlib
    ];

    shellHook = ''
      # use a Gem directory within nix
      export GEM_HOME=$out/.gems
      export PATH=$out/.gems/bin:$PATH

      # For nokogiri
      export XSLT_LIB=${stdenv.lib.makeLibraryPath [ libxslt ]}
      bundle config build.nokogigi --with-xslt-lib=$XSLT_LIB
    '';
    }
```

I think the key bits are the `XSLT_LIB` var and the `bundle config` bit